# How can I keep colorful terminal output, but disable pagers

Tags: osx, colors, man, less, pager

On macOS man uses the pager "/usr/bin/less -is" (see man's man page). When I type man , I see colorized output, and I like this. But, I prefer to use the terminal's find commands when using man, and see less's paging behavior as an obstacle.

If I set the pager to cat, I lose coloring.

How can I disable paging, but keep coloring?

Comment: I don't have macOS to try it on, but you could also try unsetting PAGER and MANPAGER or setting them to the empty string.

Comment: Good idea. I checked, and PAGER and MANPAGER are both unset in my shell sessions. If I explicitly set them to empty strings, man fails to run.

Comment: The Fedora man man page says if you set `MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1` in the environment, output to a pipe will keep formatting chars.

Comment: That sounded promising, but "MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING=1 man man | cat" executed from a bash shell results in unformatted output. "man man" on macOS doesn't mention MAN_KEEP_FORMATTING.

Answer (score 1):

If you pipe the output of man to another program, such as `cat(1)`, the output will appear unformatted, however if you look at the output of `cat` with a hexdump program such as `xxd(1)`, you will see that it has retained its formatting.

```
man man | xxd
```

The formatting is expressed by using the backspace character, `0x08`, for bold formatting and underlining. To underline a character, first the underscore character is printed, then the backspace character follows, which moves the cursor back one position, then the character to be underlined is written. To make a bold character, the character is written, the cursor is moved back one position, then the character is written again. The result of this on a hardcopy terminal would have the intended effect, but in our terminal emulation program the second character overwrites the first and it appears as though there is no formatting. This formatting can be converted to the format used by your terminal by using the `ul(1)` program.

```
man man | ul
```

Now, when you examine the byte encoding of the output of this pipeline you will see `ESC` codes or whatever other codes are or are not used by the terminfo/termcap terminal description that `ul` decided to use.

```
man man | ul | xxd
```

Note that both `more` and `less` convert control codes like `ESC` to a form that makes them apparent to the user, so that the user would know if there were control codes embedded in the file he was examining. If you want to page the output of `ul` and have the terminal interpret the `ESC` codes, you would have to configure the pager to output raw character codes. You can use the `-r` or `-R` options of `less` or `more` to achieve this.

```
man man | ul | less -r
```

Note that these options are not included in the default options that are passed to `less`, which is invoked as `less -is`.

If you want to see the `ESC` codes but without paging, you can use the `-v` option of `cat`.

```
man man | ul | cat -v
```

---

The above explains how you can recover the formatting for underlined and bold text, but it does not output color, even if `less` was configured to output it. (Note that `less` can be set to output color by using `LESS_TERMCAP_*` environment variables, a capability which is not listed in the manual page for `less` on MacOS Big Sur 11.7.3 but which nonetheless works, and is documented in the more up-to-date `less` documentation at https://github.com/gwsw/less/blob/919fcc8222ebbe8a25f3f81a735222b8fdc78433/less.nro.VER#L2252. Presumably the manual page for `less` that is distributed with Big Sur is out of date relative to the actual program. See https://www.2daygeek.com/get-display-view-colored-colorized-man-pages-linux/ for some examples of using the `LESS_TERMCAP_*` environment variables.) However, `ul` has a `-t` option to specify the terminal description to use, so we can create our own modified terminal description that prints bold and underline how we want. Here is an example terminfo description that builds on the `xterm-256color` terminfo description:

```
xterm-256color-manpipecolors|xterm-256color with preset colors for retaining color in piped manpages,
    blink=\E[1;31m,
    bold=\E[1;36m,
    sgr0=\E[0m,
    smso=\E[01;44;33m,
    rmso=\E[0m,
    smul=\E[1;32m,
    rmul=\E[0m,
    use=xterm-256color,
```

Assuming this file is named `xterm-256color-manpipecolors`, this can be compiled into `~/.terminfo` with the following command:

```
tic xterm-256color-manpipecolors
```

The terminfo description could be used for unpaged output like this:

```
man man | ul -t xterm-256color-manpipecolors
```

but if you want to page the output of this pipeline you'll have to set your pager to output the raw characters:

```
man man | ul -t xterm-256color-manpipecolors | less -r
```

We can clean this up by using the `MANPAGER` environment variable, and we can see that the result even works when piped to `cat`, thereby avoiding paging:

```
MANPAGER='ul -t xterm-256color-manpipecolors | less -isr' man man
MANPAGER='ul -t xterm-256color-manpipecolors | less -isr' man man | cat
```

If you put

```
export MANPAGER='ul -t xterm-256color-manpipecolors | less -isr'
```

in your `~/.bashrc` so it gets invoked at the start of a shell, you can get both paging and non-paging behavior from `man` in a rather succinct way:

```
man man       # with color and paging
man man | cat # with color and without paging
```

It would be my guess that this works because `less` checks whether `stdout` is a tty, and that if it isn't a tty it's hardcoded to not bother with printing tty codes or paging the output.